# Finding highest grade from 3 column csv

Tags: c#, csv

Im trying to help my kid with C# (i can fumble through VB) but cant get anywhere here.

He has a csv with around 80 records - Lastname,firstname,score

He just has to load the csv and return the highest score and the name of the student.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace exam
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Initialise variables and setting to null.
            string FileInput = "";
            string[] arrayFirstName;
            string[] arrayLastName;
            string[] StudentDetails = new string[149];
            int Maximum = 0;
            char[] split = { ',', ' ' };

            // Input the chosen file.

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C:\\TestData.csv");
            FileInput = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Close();
            Console.WriteLine(FileInput);
            Console.ReadLine();


        }
    }
}
```

He's just starting out , and  I'll try to learn along with him but any help from you guys would be great - if I could ask , can any answers include the logic to allow me to understand?

Comment: Try using `File.ReadLines("C:\\TestData.csv")` and then use a `foreach` loop to process each line, by splitting it (`line.Split(',');` and taking the last element and parsing it to an int or double, depending on your needs. Then you can compare it with `Max`.

Comment: `File.ReadAllLines()` may be helpful to you.  It returns a `string[]` where each element is a line in the file.  You can then parse each element into something meaningful, possibly using something like `string.Split()` to split on the comma character.  From there you should have the individual data elements you need.  You can continue to derive your logic from there.

Comment: Note that `String.Split` will not work to parse a CSV file if any values contain commas (which are usually delimited with double-quotes `"`).

Comment: The first problem is parallel arrays - only homework would think that is an essential skill in 2016.  The second is that a score is going to be numeric. Getting the Min, Max or Average of an array of strings wont work.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a class that represent the records that you are trying to read from the CSV file.

That I suggest that you use a CSV parser library (like CsvHelpers from nuget) that can read the CSV for you and return a list with CSV records.

CsvHelpers is a good library with some good documentation: http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/

That you can use Linq to find the highest grade.

Comment: Thanks guys, The problem is that as Plutonix mentions - its homework so he's restricted on what he can use. Do you think the existing code tweaked would be possible to output the desired result?